# How to slide div right to left and left to right smoothly with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on some animation where when the user clicks on any click the page will slide 60px left and when a new page loads it will slide from 60px right to the center

I have created this code but it's not smooth as this reference site: https://www.jacquemus.com/shop/women/tops
Is it possible to create animation like this with CSS and JS

```js
var elts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-animate]');
if(elts){
var show = function() { 
  document.getElementById("main").classList.remove('fadeOutLeft');
    document.getElementById("main").classList.add('fadeOutRight');
}

for (var i = elts.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    elts[i].onclick = show;
     }}
```

```css
 .features--show-page-transition_cus{
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
 .header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes fadeOutRight {
     0% {
            opacity: 0.9;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
  
     100% {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(-60px, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeOutRight {
     0% {
         opacity: 0.9;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
  
    
     100% {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(-120px, 0);
    }
}
 .fadeOutRight {
     -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutRight;
     animation-name: fadeOutRight;
      
}
 .fadeOutLeft{
     -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
     animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
       overflow-x: hidden;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(60px, 0);
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 1;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
}
 @keyframes fadeOutLeft {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: translate(60px, 0);
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 1;
         -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<a data-animate href="/pages">main</a>
<a data-animate href="/pages">main</a>
<a data-animate href="/pages">main</a>
<a data-animate href="/pages">main</a>
</div>

<main id ="main" class="features--show-page-transition_cus">
   
   
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

</main>
 <script>    
     document.getElementById("main").classList.add("fadeOutLeft");
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to add a referenced to the `event` argument to your `show` function and call `preventDefault()` on it. Currently clicking on the links navigates to "/pages" which does not exist in the snippets domain.

Comment: Yeah its a real example, of how it will work on the website 
But it's not smooth as https://www.jacquemus.com/shop/women/tops 
What I'm missing here
I'm trying to replica the same animation as this reference website

Comment: But it doesn't show the issue on this website. When you make a Stack Snippet for sharing code on Stack Overflow, I should be able to click Run code snippet and see what the problem is. See [mre] and [ask].